# Not able to swit To same Frame after refresh the frame

Tags: selenium, frame

I am automating 1 web application with Selenium. Application has different frame. Here is my scenario.

1. Login to the application.
2. Switch to main frame
3. Navigate to a page.
4. Switch to frame2
5. switch to frame3
6. Do some activity then Click on Save
7. Now page got refreshed. Note that complete url is not refresh. Just frame2 & frame3 got refreshed,because after save some change will be happen in frame2

Now I want to capture that change. So after refreshed I switch to defaultcontent (Assuming that when switch to default content it will switch to first frame or page content) then main then frame2. But it is not switching to any frame. I try to print the current frame with help of js script executor, it is printing nothing. Also I try with some sleep after refresh, this is also not working. I also try to switch frame by frame id/name, not work.

I am not sure after frame2 & frame3 got refresh what actually happen. In my application main frame is the first frame. I just want to switch to frame2 after save. Here is the frame structure

main --> frame2,frame3

Comment: and a link to the actual page if at all possible

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: You can use getPageSource to tell you on what frame you are.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.